# Adding an existing project to a version control system

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, mercurial

I was given a Visual Studio project which is not added to any version control system yet, and it has several "versions" which are basically folders like Project-v1, Project-v2, Project-v3 etc. How do I add all this to Mercurial? I was thinking maybe add Project-v1 to Mercurial, then copy and overwrite Project-v2 over Project-v1, commit, then copy and overwrite Project-v3, commit etc. But this is sort of clunky. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Well, it started out with a clunky way of maintaining versions, so I'd say yes, you need a clunky way to get you out of it!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25128363/import-history-from-renamed-files-and-folders-to-version-control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.

You will need to start with an empty repository, then copy the contents of "Project-v1" into the folder, and execute:

```
hg addremove
hg commit -m "<insert appropriate message here>"
```

Then, for each subsequent version, do this:

1. Delete the entire contents of the working folder, except for Mercurial-related files, like the following (but perhaps more):

   - .hg (folder)
   - .hgignore
   - .hgtags
   - .hgsub
2. Copy the contents from the version folder into the working folder
3. Execute the following Mercurial commands:

   ```
   hg addremove -s 80
   hg commit -m "<insert appropriate message here>"
   ```

   The `-s 80` parameter will handle things like files being moved or copied, as long
   as they are at least 80% similar to an existing file. If this seems to give you
   false positive, increase the number.

The point with deleting the contents of the working folder is that you will then also
commit deletion of files that doesn't exist in Project-V2, or perhaps have been moved. If
you simply copy the contents of each version folder into the working folder you will
leave the old files that was deleted or moved behind, which may not be what you want.

And yes, this is sort of clunky, but as Vince said in a comment, you have a clunky solution already in terms of the version folders so you need to get out of the clunkiness before it becomes better.